# php: undefined function sqlsrv_connect() en consola

Tags: php, sql-server, cmd

Tengo un archivo .php que realiza una conexión a una base de datos SQL Server.
Si lo ejecuto en el navegador, puedo realizar la conexión perfectamente, pero si lo ejecuto desde una consola cmd, me aparece el error: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Mi código php:

```
$servername_mssql = "server, port";
$connectionInfo_mssql = array( "Database"=>"DB","ApplicationIntent"=>"ReadOnly");
$conn_mssql = sqlsrv_connect( $servername_mssql, $connectionInfo_mssql);
```

NOTA:
Estoy corriendo el php sobre un servidor apache de WAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de wamp existen 2 archivos php.ini

Había agregado las extensiones de sql server sólo en uno de ellos, por eso, en el browser andaba, pero no en la consola.

Al agregar las extensiones en el otro php.ini automáticamente luego de reiniciar wamp anduvo.

Las rutas:

C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache\bin

C:\wamp64\bin\php\phpv